# Android How to use a Text Input in Canvas.drawColor

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, android-canvas

I have two questions you might be able to help me with, I am new at programming and this might be really easy but I looked for the answers for a couple of days and have not been able to get them. I am doing a simple android application in which you enter a hexadecimal number in a plain text field and when you click on a button a canvas gets created and you see the color from that hexadecimal number in the canvas (ex:0xff000000 you would get black) unfortunately I am not able to use the string as an integer variable into the Canvas.drawcolor(), can someone tell me how can I do this correctly, and/or why what I am doing is wrong?

My second question is how can I make the canvas appear without making my button and text field disappear from the layout when it gets created?

Here is my code, I created the toast to see if I was getting the string correctly:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private EditText mHexadecimal;
    private String comments;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHexadecimal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Hexadecimal);
        mHexadecimal.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }

public void onClick(View v) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        comments = mHexadecimal.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), comments,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mCanvas.drawColor(Integer.parseInt(comments,16));       
        mImageView = new ImageView(this);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        setContentView(mImageView);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can have a try by doing such things:

```
String color = "#FCFC0000"; //this is your color string
int colorCode = Integer.parseInt(string.replaceFirst("^#",""), 16);
```

Then try to set this **colorCode** in your `mCanvas`.